# errno150 cant create table migration

Tags: laravel-5

this my code schema goimon

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('goimon', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
            $table->charset = 'utf8';
            $table->collation = 'utf8_unicode_ci';
            $table->increments('MaGoiMon');
            $table->string('TinhTrang');
            //$table->unsignedInteger('MaNhanVien');
            $table->integer('MaNhanVien')->unsigned();
            $table->unsignedInteger('MaBan');
            $table->foreign('MaBan')->references('MaBan')->on('banan');
            $table->foreign('MaNhanVien')->references('MaNhanVien')->on('nhanvien');
            $table->timestamps();
        });


    }
```

and second schema :

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('nhanvien', function (Blueprint $table) {
             $table->engine = 'InnoDB';

            $table->increments('MaNhanVien');
            $table->string('TenNhanVien');
            $table->string('TenDangNhap');
            $table->string('MatKhau');
            $table->boolean('GioiTinh');
            $table->date('NgaySinh');
            $table->integer('CMND');
            $table->integer('quyen');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

and my error

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 
    1005 Can't create table `qlnhahang`.`#sql-12bc_
    491` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: 
    alter table `goimon` add constraint `goimon_manhanvien_foreign`
    foreign key (`MaNhanVien`) references `nhanvien` (`MaNhanVien`))
```

Comment: Please state clearly your problem and any attempts at solving it =)

Comment: Do you create the `nhanvien` table before or after `goimon`?